# How dose nginx get the value of $http_upgrade

Tags: http, nginx

In this nginx [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html), a variable `$http_upgrade` is used in nginx conf file, while this variable is not found in ngnix [var index](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), so it's probably not a built-in variable, then how nginx know its value.

Comment: It's [there](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) you just missed it. It takes its value from the [Upgrade header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header).

Answer (score 4):

The `$http_upgrade` use the value from client header `upgrade`, in nginx conf, `$http_HEADER` get the HEADER from client.

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) says:

`$http_name`

arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores

Comment: That explanation is too short for my poor brain. If $http_name is an arbitrary header field, what does it do? I found the line `proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade` in a config, and as an explanation "Sets conditions under which the response will not be taken from a cache". What is the connection between the "arbitrary request header field" and caching? I'm new to server config and find it all exceedingly confusing.